# Workflow isnt triggering at the right event moment

Tags: oracle, workflow, netsuite

I am having trouble getting a workflow to trigger at the correct moment on a transaction form Vendor Bill. The event trigger I want to use is called "After Field Sourcing" and the field I want to update is the  Due Date.

I've tried the event Trigger "Before Record Submit" and this actually alters the due date according to the formula that I have in my workflow rather than the invoice date plus payment terms. But the event trigger "After field Sourcing" does not initiate the update to the Due Date.

The Due Date field does not update when I have the event trigger set to "After Field Sourcing"

Answer (score 0):

After Field Souring is the Client Side script equivalent. Normally, I would put the After Field Sourcing action on Before Record Load and make sure the state's Do Not Exit Workflow is checked.